# Optuna pruning for validation loss

Tags: pytorch, optuna, early-stopping

I introduced the following lines in my deep learning project in order to early stop when the validation loss has not improved for 10 epochs:

```
if best_valid_loss is None or valid_loss < best_valid_loss:
    best_valid_loss = valid_loss
    counter = 0 
else:
    counter += 1 
    if counter == 10: 
        break
```

Now I want to use Optuna to tune some hyperparameters, but I don't really understand how pruning works in Optuna. Is it possible for Optuna pruners to act the same way as in the code above? I assume I have to use the following:

```
optuna.pruners.PatientPruner(???, patience=10)
```

But I don't know which pruner I could use inside PatientPruner. Btw in Optuna I'm minimizing the validation loss.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes.

Hi, I'm one of the authors of `PatientPruner` in Optuna. If we perform vanilla early-stopping, `wrapped_pruner=None` works as we expected. For example,

```py
import optuna

def objective(t):
    for step in range(30):
        if step == 5:
            t.report(0., step=step)
        else:
            t.report(step * 0.1, step=step)
        if t.should_prune():
            print("pruned at {}".format(step))
            raise optuna.exceptions.TrialPruned()
            
    return 1.

study = optuna.create_study(pruner=optuna.pruners.PatientPruner(None, patience=9), direction="minimize")
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=1)
```

The output will be `pruned at 15`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
The main objective of Optuna’s pruner is comparing between trials instead of epochs, am I right? So, wouldn’t it be possible to use early stopping (compare between epochs) and at the same time, pruning (compare between trials)? 
On the other hand, is Optuna actually using pruning to decide the best direction for hyperparameters’ optimization, or pruning is not directly related with optimization, and is just used to reduce time?